# Retrieving data from wp_users table without displaying the null values

Tags: wordpress

I am asking this question after several trial and going through the similar questions in this forum. I want to display two values (user_portal, user_url) from my wp_users table of my Wordpress site. I wrote a function for that. But problem is that the null values are also displayed which is not necessary.
My code as below:

```
function get_housenames() {
 global $wpdb;
    $houses = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT user_portal, user_url FROM 
wp_users WHERE user_url IS NOT NULL' );
    foreach ($houses as $house) {
        echo "<div class='user-box' style='background-color: #8697a8; color: 
#000; font-size: 24px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px; border-radius: 
8;'>";
        echo $house->user_portal .' <br>';
        echo "<a href class='url-box'style='color: #fff; font-size: 17px; 
margin-left: 12px; text-align: center;'>";
            echo $house->user_url;
        echo "</a>".' <br>';
        echo "</div>" .' <br>';
        }           
}
 add_shortcode('houses', 'get_housenames');
    ?>
```

Moreover I want to display the number of users of the same user_url within a pair of parenthesis alongside the displayed url, like 'www.nenow.in (12)'.

Since I am new in programming expecting an good and understandable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to INNER JOIN to same table and GROUP BY to group results. Along with NULL i'd rather check for empty strings

```
global $wpdb;
$houses = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT t1.user_portal as user_portal, t1.user_url as user_url, t2.countUsers as countUsers
    FROM wp_users AS t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT user_url, count(user_url) as countUsers
        FROM wp_users
        GROUP BY user_url
        ) AS t2
    ON t1.user_url = t2.user_url
    WHERE t1.user_url IS NOT NULL AND t1.user_url != ""
    ');
foreach ($houses as $house) {
    echo "<div class='user-box' style='background-color: #8697a8; color: #000; font-size: 24px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px; border-radius: 8;'>";
    echo $house->user_portal.' <br>';
    echo $house->user_url.'('.$house->countUsers.') <br>';
    echo "<a href class='url-box'style='color: #fff; font-size: 17px; margin-left: 12px; text-align: center;'>";
    echo $house->user_url;
    echo "</a>".' <br>';
    echo "</div>" .' <br>';
}
```

**Answering the questions**

If you want to omit counter - remove everything starting from INNER JOIN to ON. I can't understand the scenario why do you want to add DISTINCT. But I guess you want to use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.user_url) as user_url, t1.user_portal as user_portal
FROM wp_users AS t1
WHERE t1.user_url IS NOT NULL AND t1.user_url != ""
GROUP BY user_portal
```

As a result you will get an array of objects. Looping through which would look loke this

```
foreach ($houses as $house) {
    echo "<div class='user-box' style='background-color: #8697a8; color: #000; font-size: 24px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 4px; border-radius: 8;'>";
    echo $house->user_portal.' <br>';

    $user_urls = explode(',', $house->user_url);
    foreach (user_urls as $user_url) {
      echo $house->user_url.'('.$user_url.') <br>';
      echo "<a href class='url-box'style='color: #fff; font-size: 17px; margin-left: 12px; text-align: center;'>";
      echo $user_url;
      echo "</a>".' <br>';    
    }

    echo "</div>" .' <br>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Vitali actually I have no word to express my gratitude. It is working fine, as I expected. I got so many help from the Stackoverflow site. Only disappointing thing is that still I am not capable of helping others on this site since I am new to programming. I have another question, hope you do not mind, not one, two questions : 1. What to change in the code if I do not want 'the number of users part'. I mean if want to display only the user_portal and user_url without displaying the null values. 2. Do you work as freelancer? I want to write a php program for which I need help of experts.

Comment: Hi Vitali excuse me, one more thing I noticed, the DISTINCT keyword is not working here. The user_portal values are repeating which should not be.

Comment: Updated an answer

Comment: Hi Thanks again. I want to add DISTINCT because same user_url or user_portal should not be displayed more than one time which is happening. I want to display just which media houses are linked. If database included 5 names of same house through the member registration process we want just one of them to be displayed, so as user_url.

Comment: As a result you will get an array of objects - something like this [Object([user_portal] => some_value [user_url] => user_url_1,user_url_2,user_url_3)]. See the more detailed explanation above. As far as I understand your aim this should work

Comment: Sorry Vitali, I did not get the desired result. It prints the multiple instances of the urls and portals.

Comment: You can visit my site http://dimjaa.org/. See the home page and also the view where under the line Linked Media houses.

Comment: I've updated the SQL. As I could see the user_url was repeating, so added DISTINCT for this

Comment: Hi Thanks for your stickness. I manage to do this by adding the word DISTINCT to your very first example. This displays  The last also

Comment: Hi Thanks for your stickness. I managed to do this by adding the word DISTINCT to your very first example. This displays without repeating the field values. I decide to not echo the counts if I feel not necessary and do it when feel necessary. Your last edited code did not give desired result. I am still wonder why 'SELECT DISTINCT user_portal, user_url from wp_users where user_url IS NOT NULL' does not work directly. Do not we generate the result as an array and echo the values? Anyway many thanks for you patience.